# how to draw a figure eight curve using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Just as the title, how to draw a figure eight curve using tikz ? Or more general, how to use tikz to draw a parametric curve with the given parametrization ? I knew how to draw basic things by tikz like straight lines, vector, the curves using `\draw .. controls` or `\draw to[in=, out=]`, and the parametric curves is something new to me. Thanks

Comment: I do not really understand, what you are asking (maybe because my English is not good enough). What do you mean with “figure eight curve”? An octagon (eight-sided figure)? Or something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2130/277964) but with 8 instead of 9 points? Can you [show, what you've tried](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964)?

Comment: I think you should spend some time here, which you can use to express x(t) and y(t) by parameter t etc. ... https://tikz.dev/dv

Comment: @cabohah a figure-eight curve is a curve with the shape of the number eight, in math we usually call it "figure-eight curve", just like in the answer below.

Comment: You might Google Lissajous figure, also called Bowditch Curve.

Answer (score 4):

Here's something:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Figure Eight Curve
    \draw[domain   = 0:360,
          samples  = 200,
          variable = \t,
          smooth, blue, thick]
    plot ({2*cos(\t)},{2*sin(2*\t)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which generates this:

[image: Test]

Hope this is useful. Next time, please consider trying something out and showing where you failed rather than a bare-bones question.

Comment: Thank you really much. this really helpful to me.